# Object.assign() ignore undefined or empty values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using `Object.assign()` to add attributes to HTML

```
const { attr1, attr2, attr3  } = attributes;

return Object.assign({ 
    ['data-attr-1']: attr1,
    ['data-attr-2']: attr2, 
    ['data-attr-3']: attr3,
});
```

If a value is empty it is still creating the HTML attribute. Is it possible to ignore properties with an empty value?

Note: I can use only the `Object.assign()` for this

Comment: `['data-attr-1']:` is `'data-attr-1':`.

Comment: `it is still creating the HTML attribute` and why should that be bad?!

Comment: *"Note: I can use only the `Object.assign()` for this"* So nothing else? No other methods or syntax features?

Comment: @CrazyTrain nope

Comment: So then this is some kind of a code challenge?

Comment: You're not actually *using* `Object.assign` in the code you posted? Calling it with a single argument will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value and map only truthy values with an object.

```js
var attr1 = undefined,
    attr2 = 'foo',
    attr3 = null;

console.log(Object.assign(
    {}, 
    ...[attr1, attr2, attr3].map((v, i) => v && { ['data-attr-' + (i + 1)]: v })
));
```

Comment: The incrementing numeric nature of the data attribute names is most likely mere sample data, since in nearly all cases in the real world, data attributes actually have useful, descriptive names.